# Determining color based on user input

Tags: c, parsing, input, compare

I'm working on a parser for my raytracer in C that reads user input (to describe a scene). I want the user to be able to write in a color in this format:

```
sphere:
{
 position: 0, 0, 0
 radius: 1
 color: white
}
```

I want to give the user many options. In the past, for colors in other projects, I used a large header file with defines for colors in hexadecimal format like this:

```
# define BLACK 0x000000
...
```

But i can't quite iterate through my defines and compare to user input ...
**What is the most practical way to read the user input and determine what color the user gave?** Remember, I have dozens and dozens of colors and i want to be able to add new ones easily. I kinda want to avoid doing this for every color:

```
if (!strcmp(user_input, "red"))
    return (0xFF0000);
if ...
```

But could there be a practical way of doing this in a loop with a predefined table of colors and values?

Comment: Could you try a nested for loop?

Comment: From @Christian Ceballos (not enough rep to comment): Could you try a nested for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easiest (?) would probably be to not hardcode this, but instead:

1. Define a textual format that defines colors (could be something super-simple with just a name and a hex triplet per line)
2. Read in the file once at start-up
3. Prepare the data in memory for rapid search: sort it (using [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)), so you can use binary search (using [`bsearch()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch)).

Then whenever you need to look up a color, do a search in the color file data and you're done.

I imagine an API perhaps like this:

```
// Returns number of loaded colors, or -1 on error.
int colordb_init(const char *filename);

// Returns true on success, false if the color is not known.
bool colordb_lookup(const char *name, uint32_t *rgb);
```

This could all be implemented in perhaps 100-150 lines of code, and would be very fast (binary-searching packed arrays is quick), not that I expect the speed of the color-lookup to become a bottleneck in a raytracer very soon. :)

[This list from X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) is usually available on disk on Unix:y systems, else you can copy-paste it from Wikipedia as a starting point.

Comment: Looks more like an application for a hash-table. Anyway, the question is too broad.

Comment: A solution like this is exactly what i was looking for! Since this is a school project, I am limited to what functions I can use. In this case, I would have to create my own qsort and bsearch, but the idea of having an external file and parsing it at start-up is great. Thanks!